# Converting varchar to date for range SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, range, varchar, sql-convert

I am trying to convert from a varchar field in TSQL to Date -

> The error I'm getting is conversion of varchar to date in US m/d/y mm/dd/yy format resulted in an index out of range

This is my query

```
select *
from test_revision2
where test_revision2.location ='Downsview' AND
      not exists (select 1
                  from test_bookings2
                  WHERE ((CONVERT(DateTime, startDate, 103) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '11/31/2017 00:00:01', 103)) 
AND (CONVERT(DateTime, endDate, 103) >= CONVERT(DateTime, '11/30/2017 00:00:01', 103))  and
                        test_bookings2.wsid = test_revision2.wsid));
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are converting the dates on your WHERE clause?

Comment: The 103 format is `dd/mm/yyyy`, and as far as I know, there's no month number 30

Comment: Thanks for the help @lanak changed it to 101 and realized theres no Nov 31 and it worked

Comment: What is startDate and endDate dataype?  If it's a datetime, you can eliminate CONVERT in the left side of your conditions (ie startDate<= CONVERT...